# select one of many attributes from xml element using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I need to extract one of the many attributes that one of the xml tag contains using xPATH.
I get an xml payload and what I am running is a mule application.
Here is the sample xml that I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" bme:version="1-0" xsi:schemaLocation="">
<env:Header>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
        <smrst:abc xmlns:smrst="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-result" xmlns:smc="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-core" smc:applcode="123" smc:appInter="abc" smc:applicationId="123456ACV 20121203000000001239" smc:bC="111" smc:bT="GHJ" smc:ent="GHJ123" smc:mT="ASDFGH" smc:NH="33" smc:BH="0">

</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

of the above sample xml I would like to extract smc:NH value and smc:BH value uisng xpath.

This is what I have tried and get null. Please guide me.

```
<logger message="value for hit 1'st #[xpath:Envelope/Body/abc/@smc:NH]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

when I try following I get an error not sure what am I missing.

```
<logger message="value for hit #[xpath:/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='abc']/@applcode]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

btw, these are just log statements, I need to extract the values and set it to another variable.

Comment: "i get an error" - what error?

Comment: Remove the quotes `'` from the attribute name in `/'@applicationCode'`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the mule xml namespace manger for the namespaces your xpath is looking for as below.

```
<xm:namespace prefix="env"  uri="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />

<xm:namespace prefix="smrst"  uri="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-result" />         

<xm:namespace prefix="smc"  uri="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-core" />
```

And then change your xpath as below.

```
#[xpath://env:Envelope/env:Body/smrst:abc/@smc:NH]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added namespaces to the mule xml config. like below

Comment: I added the namespaces to the mule config and changed the xpath expression as you mentioned. 
But i get following error now. 
Cannot resolve namespace prefix 'env' (org.jaxen.UnresolvableException).

THis is how the addition of new namespaces looks in my mule-xml config. xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:smrst="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/abc-model-result" xmlns:smc="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/abc-model-core"

This is how xpath looks like now.

#[xpath://env:Envelope/env:Body/smrst:SanctionsResult/@smc:applicationCode]

Comment: I am using xPATH expression to ignore teh namespace values 

<logger message="value for hit #[xpath:/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='abc']/@appcode]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
but this returns null. any idea what am i missing?

Comment: @user2160677 Did you add those `xm:namespace` entries as user1760178 suggested, or just the stuff you pasted in that comment?

Comment: Did you get it working after adding the namespaces using namespacemanager to mule config.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems with your sample `XML`.

1. The prefix "bme" for attribute "bme:version" associated with an element type "env:Envelope" is not bound.
2. The element type `<smrst:abc>` is not terminated with end tag.

Correct `XML` first and then add namespace manager to your mule config

```
   <xm:namespace-manager>
        <xm:namespace prefix="env" uri="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />
        <xm:namespace prefix="smrst" uri="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-result" />
        <xm:namespace prefix="smc" uri="http://abc.xyz.com/2013/123-model-core" />
    </xm:namespace-manager>
```

And then do this `XPath`:

`<logger message="Value of NH is: #[xpath('//env:Envelope/env:Body/smrst:abc/@smc:NH').value]" level="INFO" />`

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, you either need to declare your namespaces and use namespace prefixes properly, or use `local-name()` for everything, as you are already doing for the elements:

```
<logger message="value for hit #[xpath:/*[local-name()='Envelope']
                                       /*[local-name()='Body']
                                       /*[local-name()='abc']
                                       /@*[local-name() = 'applcode']" 
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Personally, I would recommend properly declaring and using namespace prefixes, as others have suggested.